# How can I get notified when Google map is updated?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm designing a website that heavily uses Google Map API. Basically, I put a lot of overlays (polygon mostly) on top the the Map with the lat and lng stored in a local database.

I'm worrying about maintenance of the site. Lets say if the map is changed (e.g: a new bridge is built). How can I be informed so I can update my local database accordingly? Is there any way to subscribe to the change, let says if any change to NewYork map area then I will be informed by email?

Thank you very much,
LegolasV

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do not think they give you notification for Google Maps, but you can set up your own notification by using the [Google Maps Static Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).

You can set the map to display your monitor area, and download the image, hash (MD5 is enough) the file, and you store the hash.
Since they are the same file, you should get the same hash.

I tried it on [this image](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn%20Bridge,New%20York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284),
downloaded it from 2 different browser and both image gave me a MD5 hash of 
`2451A7F36C9007BA495C4BD785695F28`

So this workaround should works.

Comment: And how often would you check this?

Comment: it really depends on your need. I would say once a day doesn't hurt. you can write a small program to do this daly, and host it on those free servers like openshift.